# When using multiple tag filters, the "new activity" prompt loads incorrect posts

Tags: support

Example, using a [multiple tag filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays%20javascript?sort=Newest&edited=true)

[image: multiple tag filter]

Hitting "Apply filter" or reloading the page loads the correct posts having both tags.

However, when the new activity prompt shows up

[image]

clicking it reveals posts with only one of the tags. Reloading the same page removes those posts and returns to a list containing posts with both tags

Comment: @Kaiido If it had an answer it might

Comment: That's still the same bug report -> a dupe. Yes the auto-comment is bad, not my fault.

Comment: This one mentioned in that post seems more applicable ~ [“X questions with new activity” showing incorrect information in windows with multiple tag filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343767/x-questions-with-new-activity-showing-incorrect-information-in-windows-with-mu)

Comment: I must be missing something. I don't see an answer on that one either

Comment: Nope, I did miss something ;-) sorry